# How do I update a new reference in a OneToOne bidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two simple entities

```
//Address @Entity     
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

and

```
//User @Entity
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
Address address;
```

But I am unable to update the user with a new address.

**First approach:**

```
    Address address = new Address();
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");
    address.setUser(user);
    addressRepository.save(address);
```

the code runs fine but an insert statement is done and now I have two address records in the database which causes future exceptions.

**Second approach**

```
Address address = new Address();
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");
    address.setUser(user);
    user.setAddress(address);   //added this line
    addressRepository.save(address);
```

Now it throws exception

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

**Third approach**

```
Address address = new Address();
User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");
address.setUser(user);
user.setAddress(address); 
userRepository.save(user);  //added this
addressRepository.save(address);
```

New exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

---

**Temp solution**

This solution works, but it's the most ugly code I've written and also I have no idea why it works. If someone has a better answer I will mark as solution.

**First add cascade to the entity**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Address address;
```

And then update using this:

```
User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");
    if (user.getAddress() != null) {
        addressRepository.delete(user.getAddress());
        user.setAddress(address);
        address.setUser(user);
        userRepository.save(user);
    } else {
        address.setUser(user);
        addressRepository.save(address);
    }
```

Comment: First approach is wrong, but shouldn't get the behaviour you see without there being a lot more to it. Save should only see the one address, so you are doing something to get it in the EntityManager context (transaction) twice that you haven't shown after this save call - maybe look at using what Save returns if you are going to continue processing with this new Address instance. The second way is the more correct way of dealing with the relationship, so you'll want look at the statement causing the exception - show the SQL generated and we can help figure out where/why it is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

> //Address @Entity
>
> ```
> @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
> @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
> private User user;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> //User @Entity
> @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
> Address address;
> ```

According to the above code, you have declared that the entity `Address` will be the one that has the mapping for the relevant `User`. So your `Address` table in database has an extra field `user_id` that maps this address with the relevant user.

Check your 1st approach

```
Address address = new Address();                         <--- new address entity created
User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");  <--- user retrieved from DB
address.setUser(user);                                   <----New address record in address table is set up to have the relevant user
addressRepository.save(address);
```

You should do it the other way around

Also add **@Transactional** to the method that executed the following code

```
Address address = new Address();                        
User user = userRepository.findByUsername("someemail");  
if (user.getAddress() != null) {
    Address oldAddress = user.getAddress();
    oldAddress.setUser(null);
}
user.setAddress(address);                                 
userRepository.save(user);
```

For this to work you have to modify in your `User` entity the

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 Address address;
```

Now when you execute the above code, the previous address entity will be updated to have a `null` reference for a `user` and this way the `orphanRemoval` will do it's job and remove it from database while the new address will be persisted and linked with the relative user.

Comment: Same error. org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: @erotsppa can it be that your database has trash data from before? Could you try to clean it and try again?

Comment: It works when the user has no address but will throw exception if it already has address which is the whole objective here. To update address

Comment: @erotsppa yes I understand your requirment but the point is that you may have bad data from before in DB. That is why I asked you to clean and try again to insert user with address and then update the adress.

Comment: Cleaned and try again. Same problem

Comment: @erotsppa please update the question and share all the code which get's executed which results into `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` I believe there is more code into that

Comment: There is not, I copied your code and ran it

Comment: @erotsppa check updated answer and don't forget the `@Transactional`

Comment: At the save() method it throws this: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.para.user.models.User.address -> com.para.TL.models.Address]

Answer (score 1):

This is the final working answer

```
//address entity, no cascade non sense
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private User user;
```

and

```
 //User @Entity
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
Address address;
```

And then update reference by

```
  if (user.getAddress() != null) {
        user.setAddress(null);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    address.setUser(user);
    addressRepository.save(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
 @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
 Address address;
}
```

When you put the orphanRemoval on the @OneToOne ,the User table in the database will have a field created as a FK with PK of the adress table,so that hibernate can keep track of changes. When you try to save a User ,even without changing the adress value ,a select query will be triggered to CHECK if there's any difference between the selected adress fields and the adress object contained in the user object that you passed to the save method.If there's any change ,a select will be triggered on the adress table to see if that record is still there ,and if so ,after updating the user table , a delete query will be issued to delete that orphan adress.
hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You and Thomas Edison have a lot in common ...

```
    User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
    user.getAddress().setSomething("YYY");
    addressRepository.save(user.getAddress());
```

Really though, you should not make problems for yourself. If you do, print the SQL to see what's going on.

```
    User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
    addressRepository.delete(user.getAddress());
    user = userRepository.save(user);
    addressRepository.save(Address.builder().something("YYY").user(user).build());
```

I would do this differently.

```
// Address
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
private User user;

// User
@OneToOne
private Address address;
```

and

```
    User user = userRepository.findById(2L).get();
    user.setAddress(addressRepository.save(Address.builder().something("YYY").user(user).build()));
    userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: While this works to set something on the existing user's existing address, doesn't answer the question on how to point a user to a new address, or what is going wrong in their current attempts at creating a new address.

Comment: And why would you want to do that?